# what constitutes a card draw?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Dragons of Tarkir has a new Planeswalker - [Narset Transcendent](http://mythicspoiler.com/dtk/cards/narsettranscendent.html) - that, among other things, let's you "*look at the top card of your library; if it's a noncreature, nonland card, you may reveal it and put it into your hand*".

How does that interact with cards like [Maralen of the Mornsong](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152546), which says, among other things, "*Players can't draw cards*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only counts as a draw if the effect or rule specifically says "draw." Otherwise, it's just an action that **resembles** drawing a card. Specifically, Maralen of the Mornsong will not prevent you from putting cards in your hand with Narset.

This is specified by rule [120.5](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Drawing_a_Card):

> If an effect moves cards from a player's library to that player's hand without using the word "draw," the player has not drawn those cards. This makes a difference for abilities that trigger on drawing cards and effects that replace card draws, as well as if the player's library is empty.